# How to call methods from the super class?

Tags: super, gridworld

This bug is supposed to be irremovable from the grid by itself.  Is there a way to make the ConnorBug do the removeSelfFromGrid() from the original Bug class and actually get rid of the bug from the grid?

```
public class ConnorBug extends Bug
{
    public static int MyNewCounter = 0;
    public ConnorBug()
    {
        setColor(null);
    }
    public void removeSelfFromGrid()
    {
        Location loc = getLocation();
        Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
        Location next = loc.getAdjacentLocation(getDirection());
        if(gr.isValid(next))
        {

            this.move();
        }
        else{
            this.setDirection(getDirection()-180);
            this.move();
        }
        for(int c=0; c<8; c++)
        {

            Location thatLoc = getLocation();
            Location thatNext = thatLoc.getAdjacentLocation((0+(45*c)));
            if(gr.isValid(thatNext)&&!(gr.get(thatNext) instanceof ConnorRock)&&!(gr.get(thatNext) instanceof ConnorBug))
            {

                ConnorRock something = new ConnorRock();
                something.putSelfInGrid(gr,thatNext);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use:

```
super.<method name>();
```

Either if the function is static, you can just `Bug.<method name>();`

Comment: So another bug would have '<ConnorBug>.super.removeSelfFromGrid()' for the ConnorBug to do the removeSelfFromGrid() from the super class correct?

Comment: sometimes it's better to test yourself in your env, in this kind of work you will learn this issue better.